# n-arry tree from file (left child right siblings)

Tags: c++, tree

I have to construct a n-ary tree by left child right sibling representation. I have here a structure Node. But I can't figure it out how to write the keys in the file.

```
struct Node
{
    int data;

    int siblingsNumber;

    Nod *LeftChild;

    Nod **siblings;

    Nod(int key, int siblingsNr)
    {
        data = key;
        siblingsNr = siblingsNumber;
        siblings = new Node*[siblingsNr];
    }
};
```

Comment: This small sample is ful of typos: any occurrence of `Nod` must be `Node`.

Comment: 1. For an n-ary tree, I would'nt store a pointer to left child and a container with siblings. Are there specific reasons for your design? It feels unusual (to me). Instead, I would use a container for pointer to all children. 2. Instead of an array created with `new`, I warmly recommend to use `std::vector` for this.

Comment: I may use std::vector, but the exercise say that i have to use left child right sibling representation

Comment: Then probably each node should point to its right sibling only, hence `Node *rightSibling;` instead of `Node **siblings;`.